# Grid order with multiple take profits

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to have a grid order with multiple take profits? By grid order I mean, multiple entries with different prices spread within a range. I know I can have multiple take profits and grid orders, but could not find them together.

I could not find any reference of this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple entries. You need to set your `pyramiding` parameter accordingly.

Then just use the `strategy.entry()` for the entries and you can use `strategy.cancel()` or `strategy.cancel_all()` to cancel any pending orders.